# Challenges with Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

1. Unable to make a copy of the database using the following SQL command or through the Azure portal

   - `CREATE DATABASE mydatabase_copy AS COPY OF mydatabase;`
2. Unable to make a copy of the database on Azure SQL Server, no wizard is present

   - we know there is a way of creating bacpac and restoring it, but this is a complete manual process and take too much time
   - we need some automated way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CREATE DATABASE ... AS COPY OF is not available in [Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-mi-current&preserve-view=true&tabs=sqlpool), only in [SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true&tabs=sqlpool).  Instead use [Point-in-time restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/point-in-time-restore?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal)

> Use point-in-time restore (PITR) to create a database as a copy of
> another database from some time in the past. This article describes
> how to do a point-in-time restore of a database in Azure SQL Managed
> Instance.
>
> Point-in-time restore is useful in recovery scenarios, such as
> incidents caused by errors, incorrectly loaded data, or deletion of
> crucial data. You can also use it simply for testing or auditing.
> Backup files are kept for 7 to 35 days, depending on your database
> settings.

Which you can automate with [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/point-in-time-restore?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#powershell-1).